# Data of Credit Migration Matrices

Tags: forecasting, credit-risk

Please advise that how to get the data of credit migration matrices

There is a paper of credit migration matrices, I would import the data to Matlab or R for credit analysis. 
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227992149_Credit_Migration_Matrices

Thank you.

Regards, 
Nelson.

Comment: Moody's and Standard & Poors publish such matrices from time to time.

Comment: Unfortunately with the S&P ratings, the rating is not in term of timeseries https://www.standardandpoors.com/en_US/web/guest/ratings/ratings-actions. If anyone is able to find any historical S&P credit ratings by country, please post them.

Comment: ESMA publishes some of rating agencies' data on their CEREP database: https://cerep.esma.europa.eu/cerep-web/statistics/ratingActivity.xhtml. Might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately with the S&P ratings, the rating is not in term of timeseries

http://www.standardandpoors.com/en_US/web/guest/home

If anyone is able to find any historical S&P credit ratings by country, please post them.